# Problems when installing ROS2 Foxy for Windows

Tags: ros2, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to install ROS2 Foxy and am following the following page https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Windows-Install-Binary/#id13.

After doing the following command:

```
call C:\dev\ros2_foxy\local_setup.bat
```

I get the following error

```
[connext_cmake_module] Warning: The location at which Connext was found when the workspace was built [[C:\Program Files\rti_connext_dds-5.3.1]] does not point to a valid directory, and the NDDSHOME environment variable has not been set. Support for Connext will not be available.
```

I was wondering how I could fix this problem, I have tried to search online, but couldn't fix the problem. If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361244/problems-when-installing-ros2-foxy-for-windows/) by [Someone0135](https://answers.ros.org/users/59194/someone0135/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Warning: [...] Support for Connext will not be available.

This warning means you won't be able to use the rmw implementation Connext. As long as you don't need Connext (the default rmw implementation is Fast-RTPS/Fast-DDS), you can ignore that warning.

If you want to use Connext and make the warning go away, see this documentation on how to install Connext with the Windows Binary install: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/DDS-Implementations/#windows-binary-install

You might be interested in some of this other documentation

- information about RMW implementations https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Concepts/DDS-and-ROS-middleware-implementations/
- tutorial about using different RMW implementations https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Working-with-multiple-RMW-implementations/

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Someone0135](https://answers.ros.org/users/59194/someone0135/) on 2020-09-12**:
Thanks for the answer!